# Instant App module running but Apk module not working

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

Hi Am working on a project where i have to create both installable and instant apk. It is actually a installable app, now I migrated to instant app. After configuration both the module works fine. But now only instant module is working but not APK module. But it is telling default activity not found in APK module. Can anyone know what is the issue?

[image]

I don't know why it is telling, I have not updated anything on apk module debug configuration it was working well. But now it is not working. Can anyone have solution for this issue?

Here is my apkmodule manifest.xml

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="xxx.xxxx.xxx">
   </manifest>
```

Comment: Share your app modules manifest

Comment: added apkmodule manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bug in android studio caused by an external library library where manifest merging fails.

[I filed the issue here, there is a workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79671572)

> Workaround: if you build from the command line, gradle does the manifest merging correctly for the installable app.

As a second workaround that worked for me: Add the application tag and activity tag to your apkmodule manifest until you finish testing the remove it.
Note: the activity name has to be the fully qualifying name.

Comment: I have not used android architecture component

Comment: I guess it can be caused by any other library, the workaround still hold and the bug is still the same just with a different manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Like say @Khaled Emara, i think it's a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79671572). Maybe you are not using android architecture component  but some library does

Have you try to install the app with command line ?

```
./gradlew installDebug
```